# Copy from one book to another

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Im trying to copy some data from one book to another... But I have no Idea how.
Right now what it does its copy to another "sheet" "REGISTRO" (in the same book)

Is it posible to copy the data to "sheet Registro" but in another existing book?

```
Sub REGISTRO()
filalibre = Sheets("registros").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Select

fila = 10


While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("E4") 'factura
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("E2") 'fecha
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("C6") 'cliente
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 8) = ActiveSheet.Range("f26") 'subtotal
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 9) = ActiveSheet.Range("f27") 'saldo
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 10) = ActiveSheet.Range("f28") 'total

Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) 'cantidad
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 5) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) 'producto
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 6) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) '$/unidad
Sheets("registros").Cells(filalibre, 7) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) 'subotal


filalibre = filalibre + 1

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to open the workbook first or in the code and reference it.

Comment: ok... but I dont know how to do that... can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I suggest you replace ActiveSheet with the name of the sheet. Add the path of the file to be opened.

```
Sub REGISTRO()

Dim filalibre As Long, fila As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of active sheet here") 'don't use activesheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\name of file here")
filalibre = wb.Sheets("registros").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For fila = 10 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("A" & fila) <> vbNullString Then
        With wb.Sheets("registros")
            .Cells(filalibre, 2) = ws.Range("E4") 'factura
            .Cells(filalibre, 1) = ws.Range("E2") 'fecha
            .Cells(filalibre, 3) = ws.Range("C6") 'cliente
            .Cells(filalibre, 8) = ws.Range("f26") 'subtotal
            .Cells(filalibre, 9) = ws.Range("f27") 'saldo
            .Cells(filalibre, 10) = ws.Range("f28") 'total
            .Cells(filalibre, 4) = ws.Cells(fila, 1) 'cantidad
            .Cells(filalibre, 5) = ws.Cells(fila, 2) 'producto
            .Cells(filalibre, 6) = ws.Cells(fila, 5) '$/unidad
            .Cells(filalibre, 7) = ws.Cells(fila, 6) 'subotal
        End With
        filalibre = filalibre + 1
    End If
Next fila

wb.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this... but when I run it its starts copying in loop, it never finish :S

the amount of rows that needs to copy can be from 1 to 15... I only want to copy the rows that are  <> ""

Comment: Try it now. If it doesn't work, do some debugging, step through the code etc and report back.